# client side validation on dynamic elements

Tags: jquery, validation

I have a form that a user can click a button to add another set of inputs. So I am using eName[] for example. I was hoping to use jquery to do this, and thought live() would be a great way to loop through all the elements the user created to see if they are blank but I am not sure if I can do this without binding to an event. So I am thinking something like:

```
$(form).submit(funciton()({
  //other validation here
  $(".eName").live(bindToWhat?, function() {
    //loop and check val();
  });
});
```

Or maybe this is the wrong approach.

I hope this is enough info, if not lemme know. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Don't bind to inputs, do this instead:

```
$(form).submit(funciton()({
  $(".eName").each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() === ''){
      alert('This field can not be empty');
      $(this).focus();
    }
  });
});
```

Where `eName` is supposed to be the class assigned to the fields.

Comment: each() won't pick up the new elements the user created will it? I thought each() was only aware of the elements that were created onload.

Comment: each() will iterate each element in the collection at the time of calling each. That includes dynamically created elements. The confusion comes from the fact that new elements created without a given event will not fire it unless it's added afterwards _or_ there is a .live event watching that element (by a selector)